# Using Cell Value to construct Range in excel

Tags: excel

As Example I want Cell C1 to hold SUM all rows starting from A1 till Ax,
x is changing and stored in cell B1.
Cell C1=SUM(A1:Ax)
When x=100, cell B1=100,Cell C1=SUM(A1:A100)

How to do this is with formula in Excel.

Thanks.

Comment: Either use indirect() or just in cell C1 put "=SUM(A:A)" but that will sum anything in column A.

Answer (score 1):

You could use INDEX:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,B1))
```

Comment: That works, Thank you.